# Not able to implement interface with annotations

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface, automated-tests

I am trying to implement an interface in the test classes. My interface is written as

```
public interface IBeforeAfter {
    @BeforeTest
    void initiateBrowser(String module, String serverIP, String browser);
    @BeforeClass
    void performLogin();
    @AfterMethod
    void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException;
    @AfterClass
    void performLogout();
    @AfterTest
    void closeBrowser();
}
```

Now what I want to do is to implement this interface in my test class and override these functions. But when I overrides them, I loses all the annotations applied in the interface. I there any way by which I can achieve what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: are you using aspectJ or SpringAOP ? Do you have any additional configuration?

Comment: also: if you apply the annotations on the concrete implementations, do they work then?

Comment: The annotations need to be placed in a class which can be extended. Placing them on an interface will not work. Refer to the configuration portion information - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations